# Php GET and POSTs: what is the safest way to handle them?

Tags: php, security, post

I'm already using http://php.net/pdo so I can get whatever I want from the user input, I store it in a safe way in my database.

Now I want to display what I have in my database into a Web page. How can I construct a Web page a be sure that there can be no JavaScript or whatever that will be executed when the page is displayed?

Sorry I'm very tired, I've been working for 12 hours now, if someone can correct the mistakes I've done when posting my question...

Thank you very much.

Comment: are you asking if you can disable JavaScript? What are you trying to prevent?

Comment: balanced unnecessary downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`htmlentities(stripslashes($stmt_result->data), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');`

[htmlentities()](http://php.net/htmlentities) will encode chars like > to `&gt;` and [stripslashes()](http://php.net/stripslashes) will delete backslashes from escaped string.

Comment: Manual `stripslashes` application is not an advisable approach. Rather fix incoming quotes centrally as advised by the manual. http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Comment: It has nothing to do with magic quotes. PDO will escape every string inserted in a database, so you have to delete backslashes when displaying data to a user. And I tried it on my local machince with magic quotes off.

Comment: PDO does not add extraneous backslashes. If in compatibility mode it adds some, but those are stripped by the SQL tokenizer/parser. Using real prepared statements does no escaping whatsoever. You are certainly using it wrong. Post-processing data after it returns from the database is not a proper method.

Comment: @mario, you are right, I somehow thought taht PDO add backslashes. But how will you remove them from string if you have some old entries in a database with backslashes?

Comment: You need to isolate the old entries and apply a fix only to them.

Comment: Mario it seems you're wrong about magic_quotes_gpc: from my php.ini file: "Magic quotes are a preprocessing feature of PHP where PHP will attempt to escape any character sequences in GET, POST, COOKIE and ENV data which might otherwise corrupt data being placed in resources such as databases before making that data available to you. Because of character encoding issues and non-standard SQL implementations across many databases, it's not currently possible for this feature to be 100% accurate. PHP's default behavior is to enable the feature... (follow next comment)

Comment: "We strongly recommend you use the escaping mechanisms designed specifically for the database your using instead of relying on this feature. Also note, this feature has been deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0 and is scheduled for removal in PHP 6.". So clearly I should **avoid** magic_quotes_gpc... tell me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`htmlentities`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) before outputting the text from the database.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `striptags()` and `htmlentities()`. But simply removing `<script>` blocks won't be enough, as you'll still have the `onWhatever=""` tags attributes to worry about as well.

Comment: `htmlentities(string, ENT_QUOTES)` will encode double and single quotes as well

Comment: Try, but if OP wants to let any tags through. JS can be embedded in those.

Comment: `<body onload="redirectToNastySite();">`

Comment: Did u use this function? There is no way you can do this. After using `htmlentities` your string looks so: `&lt;body onload=&quot;redirectToNastySite();&quot;&gt;`. Browser will not interpret this as body tag.